# Cannot tap on button in safari on iOS

Tags: css, angularjs, mobile-safari

I ran into this problem which does not occur often and is difficult to reproduce:
We built a web app using Angular JS. There is a button that is fixed to the bottom of the screen:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 10px;
right: 19%;
```

Normal, users can click on this button. Once in a while, they have to click on the edges of this button to make it work.

I really don't know what is happening. Can you guys help? I would greatly appreciate your effort.

--- update 20160112_1256
[here is the image for the html structure of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok3fU.png)

Comment: Can you please post how the button is set up in html?

Comment: @JordanMcRae I updated the description with the image of the html.

Comment: Hmm.. The next time you come across the issue, right click and inspect the button. It's strange that it is intermittent. The only thing I can think of is that something transparent may be blocking the link. If you inspect and notice that something is over top of the button, that may be where your problem lies.